# Convert GFM highlighted code block to Stack Overflow highlighted code block

Tags: regex, pcre, oniguruma

### 1. Question

I can't convert [**GFM highlighted code block**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/#syntax-highlighting) to [**Stack Overflow highlighted code block**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

---

### 2. Example

For example, I need convert:

````markdown
Do not change this line

```markdown
Sasha great!
    Sasha nice!
She is beautiful, surprise!
```

Do not change this line
````

to:

```markdown
Do not change this line

<!-- language: lang-markdown -->

    Sasha great!
        Sasha nice!
    She is beautiful, surprise!

Do not change this line
```

---

### 3. Problem

That get highlighted code block, I need to add tab in beginning of each line inside code block. I don't understand, how I can do it.

---

### 4. Not helped

my example regex:

- **Find**:

  ```regex
  \`\`\`(.+?)\n((.+?\n)+)\`\`\`
  ```
- **Replace**:

  ```regex
  <!-- language: lang-\1 -->\n\n\t\2
  ```

[**Demonstration on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/BCdXP6/1/).

I get result:

```markdown
Do not change this line

<!-- language: lang-markdown -->

    Sasha great!
    Sasha nice!
She is beautiful, surprise!


Do not change this line
```

Tabulation symbol added in beginning only for first line inside code block. What can I do, that add tab symbol in beginning of each line inside code block?

Comment: Any chance for doing this in Notepad++?

Comment: @revo: I use Sublime Text, not Notepad++. I don't find, how I can solve this task, use Sublime Text plugins. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about plugins but within PCRE (sublime text) chances are you can do it in two steps and not within a one-liner regular expression.

Comment: @revo: can you show, how I can solve it in 2 steps use PCRE? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Sublime Text find / replace functionality and there is no programming language involved it would take you about two steps to achieve what you desire.

For first step try to search for:

````
(?m)(?:^```\h*\S+\s+\K|\G(?!\A))^(?!```)(.*\R+)(?:```)?
````

and replace with:

```
\t\1
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fpn6Mi/1)

Second find / replace process would be for adding HTML comment so search for:

````
(?m)^```\h*(\S+)
````

and replace it with:

```
<!-- language: lang-\1 -->\n
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/VvPSon/1)